# why does hslogger not write an INFO log?

Tags: haskell, logging

I don't understand why hslogger does not write any log when calling infoM in this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

-- hslogger
import System.Log.Logger         ( Priority(INFO, WARNING), addHandler
                                 , infoM, warningM, updateGlobalLogger
                                 )
import System.Log.Handler.Simple (fileHandler)

#define INF  

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let logger = "main"


#ifdef INF 

  let fileName   = "info.log"
  h1 <- fileHandler fileName INFO
  putStrLn "opened file1"
  updateGlobalLogger logger $ addHandler h1
  putStrLn "will write1"
  infoM logger "writing 1"
  putStrLn "did write1"

#else

  let fileName = "warn.log"
  h2 <- fileHandler fileName WARNING
  putStrLn "opened file2"
  updateGlobalLogger logger $ addHandler h2
  putStrLn "will write2"
  warningM logger "writing 2"
  putStrLn "did write2"

#endif
```

When I compile and run this code, info.log is empty. However, if I comment out or remove the `#define INF`, then warn.log contains "writing 2".  Why is that?

Comment: Maybe you *really* need to use the `CPP` extension, but if you somehow could get away without it, I'd recommend you to ditch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly the default log level in `hslogger` is `WARNING`, you should set it to `INFO` if you want to see the `INFO` messages.

```
updateGlobalLogger logger $ setLevel INFO
```

Comment: Danny - Your suggestion fixed my problem.  I did not fully understand how hslogger worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  updateGlobalLogger rootLoggerName (setLevel INFO)
```